# Apache: Invalid command 'Krb5Keytab'

Tags: apache, kerberos

I am setting up Apache2 2.4.25 on Debian stretch. My conf contains following lines:

```
AuthType Kerberos
Krb5Keytab /etc/apache2/auth_kerb.keytab
KrbVerifyKDC off
```

when I restart Apache, I get this error:

```
Invalid command 'Krb5Keytab', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

How can I enable the necesary kerberos module ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the `libapache2-mod-auth-kerb` package installed? If not, I think it may be as simple as that.

I installed apache2 on a clean Debian stretch box and added your example configuration to my default `Directory`. I got the same exact error:

```
apachectl[9682]: Invalid command 'Krb5Keytab', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Once I did `apt-get install libapache2-mod-auth-kerb`, apache started successfully and all was well.